# How to set SOCKS proxy to websocket-client

Tags: python, websocket, socks

I'm trying to set a SOCKS proxy to the `websocket-client`'s `WebSocket` with `create_connection` but It always keeps closing the socket after websocket sends the handshake request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\x-python\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 252, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\x-python\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 79, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\x-python\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 162, in _get_resp_headers
    status, resp_headers, status_message = read_headers(sock)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\x-python\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_http.py", line 308, in read_headers
    line = recv_line(sock)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\x-python\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 134, in recv_line
    c = recv(sock, 1)
  File "D:\PyCharmProjects\x-python\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 125, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code -1
```

And that's how I'm trying to wrap the socket with the PySocks.

```py
from socks import socksocket
proxied_sock = socksocket()
proxied_sock.setsockopt(IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, 1)
proxied_sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
proxied_sock = self.__proxy.set_to_socket(proxied_sock)
proxied_sock.connect((dealer_str, 80))
self.__logger.debug("WS wrapped with proxy!")
self.__ws = create_connection(self.__dealer_uri, socket=proxied_sock)
```

The `set_to_socket()` function is just a function to wrap the proxy.

```py
    def set_to_socket(self, s) -> socksocket:
        """
        Sets socket's proxy
        :param s: socket.socket
        :return: Proxied socket.socket
        """
        if self.proxy_type == "http" or self.proxy_type == "https":
            s.set_proxy(HTTP, self.host, self.port, username=self.username, password=self.password)
        elif self.proxy_type == "socks4":
            s.set_proxy(SOCKS4, self.host, self.port, username=self.username, password=self.password)
        elif self.proxy_type == "socks5":
            s.set_proxy(SOCKS5, self.host, self.port, username=self.username, password=self.password)
        else:
            raise ProxyError("Proxy type not found: " + self.proxy_type)

        return s
```

Why is that happening and how can I wrap my websocket with SOCKS proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I was trying to connect to an SSL secured port so I had to wrap the socket with SSL wrapper.

```
proxied_sock = socksocket()
proxied_sock = self.__proxy.set_to_socket(proxied_sock)
dealer_tuple = (dealer_str.split(":")[0], int(dealer_str.split(":")[1]))
proxied_sock.connect(dealer_tuple)
proxied_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(proxied_sock) # We gotta wrap the socket with SSL
self.__logger.debug("Dealer client wrapped with proxy!")
self.__ws = create_connection(self.__dealer_uri, socket=proxied_sock)
```